# Data is not adding to djnago table

Tags: django

I deleted sqlite file first then created superuser before this I'd 5 tables and now am able to add manually but through form Data is not reaching & getting stored to respective tables.
Please anybody help me I tried, and still trying but unable to solve it myself

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you mean with "now am able to add manually"? Can't you just run `migrate` to create the tables again?

Comment: Hi ✋friend, Please explain what you did and what is the problem clearly.

Comment: Some code would help us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `DATABASES` configuration in the `settings.py` file points to the correct SQLite file.

run migrations (`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`) to apply the changes to the database.